# Create reference to non loaded preact component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am trying to change some text in a preact component based on an object the user clicks in this [threejs scene](https://starmap.surge.sh). I am using [Matt DesLauriers' template](https://github.com/mattdesl/threejs-app) for this app as I wanted to see how professionals might do it. This is the first time I have used react(although its actually preact) aswell as threeJS.

In theory my method should work except for one problem. The way Matt DesLauriers set up the loading screen means that the main UI component, named Landing, is rendered after the loading has finished. This achieved by

```
getContent (section) {
    // You are probably better off using a real "Router" for history push etc.
    // NB: Ensure there is a 'key' attribute so transition group can create animations
    switch (section) {
      case 'Preloader': return <Preloader key='Preloader' />;

      default:
      case 'Landing': return <Landing key='Landing'/>;
    }
  }

  render () {
    const classes = classnames({
      'App': true
    });

    const section = this.state.section;
    const content = this.getContent(section);

    // Render the WebGL if loaded
    // And also render the current UI section on top, with transitions
    return (
      <div className={classes} ref={ c => { this.container = c; } }>
        { this.state.isLoaded && <WebGLCanvas />}

        <PreactTransitionGroup className='content' >
          { content }
        </PreactTransitionGroup>

      </div>

    );
  }
```

I need to be able to reference Landing so I can set it's state, however giving it a ref  `case 'Landing': return <Landing key='Landing'  ref={this.ref}/>;` results in a reference to an empty object. If I put the Landing component in directly it works exactly as intended.

Any idea how to fix this?

Also here is the [public GitHub repo](https://github.com/3swordjack/CollectiveMap) if you want.

Comment: The ref is updated on every render, it should give you an empty object while it is loading, but then return the expected object after it's done. If this is not happening, something else must be wrong. Can you provide an example of this problem in codesandbox.io? That way we can help you.

Comment: @RicardoLopes ill try, but im not sure ill be able to replicate the complexity of the situation from scratch. If you would like https://github.com/3swordjack/CollectiveMap is my github repo

Comment: @RicardoLopes, I was unable to succesfully make something editable online work. Any other ideas?